# Getting errors when installing PHP via Chef Solo

Tags: php, chef-solo

I got pretty far in this doc.
http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html

up to the PHP install steps. Got through downloading php and including php in the default.rb

However getting the following errors when running chef-solo

Recipe: php::package
  * yum_package[php] action install (up to date)
  * yum_package[php-devel] action install
    * No version specified, and no candidate version available for php-devel
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[php-devel]'
    ================================================================================

```
Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
No version specified, and no candidate version available for php-devel
```

Chef Solo just quits.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
FG

Answer (score 0):

No "php-devel" is needed on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago).

I removed "php-devel" from `/root/chef-repo/cookbooks/php/attributes/default.rb`, and got it work now.